# How to Load the Same UIVew with Different Data from a Table List?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, detailsview

I have a small project where I'm trying to build a recipe list for a game. I have my UITableView running great - the only problem is that I don't know how to connect each cell with a DetailView. Currently if you select any of the cells it does the selection animation and goes nowhere.

I also don't know what the best way to approach this would be using the newest iOS5 SDK & Xcode 4.2. I am barely familiar with storyboards but I assume there must be an easier way than creating 40 different DetailViews for each recipe.

My hope was to create a new Recipe.h/Recipe.m Object set and hold all the data in there. Then it could be loaded into the same DetailView template, but the information would change depending on which recipe was selected. I hope this makes sense?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything. I've attached [my project source code](http://cl.ly/D62T) if this would be helpful... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, add this piece of code to your `MasterViewController.m`,

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
```

Then open your MainStoryboard.storyboard, then follow these steps :

1. Add a `UITableViewCell` to the tableview in MasterView.
2. In the cell's Inspector, select style as Basic, and give its identifier as "Cell".
3. Control + click the cell and drag a line till DetailView and select `Push` option. You should be able to see a Storyboard segue. Give its identifier as "showDetail".
4. Then go to `MasterViewController.m` and comment the following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

   This is because you are already getting a cell from

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
5. Then add the following code in MasterViewController.m

   ```
   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
     {
       DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       [dvc setDetailItem:[self.harvestRecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     }
   }
   ```

Build and run. You should be good to go.

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm building the cells dynamically in Objective-C. So I can't just drag from a static cell to the DetailView, because there needs to be a way for me to determine which cell was originally tapped. So for example if the user taps "Ice Cream" in the table view the DetailView will display that. but if the user taps "Sandwich" I need to load the SAME detail view except somehow load a sandwich instead - I'm not sure which variable would hold the index/label of the tapped cell.